# LineageOS fail to update

Tags: twrp, rom-update, lineageos

I've a wileyfox swift (crackling) and I've installed LineageOS 14.1-20170213-NIGHTLY-cracking + GApps through TWRP 3.0.3.

The problem is that when I try to update it through the UI or manually (downloading the .zip file from https://download.lineageos.org/ and installing it from the recovery) TWRP returns an error (status error 7).

I tried to downgrade TWRP to the 3.0.0 version but nothing changed.

How can I update my phone without wipe everything?

Comment: lineageos feb 20 build has error 7 on most devices, today's build also had same error(feb 27), but solved by a image file called boot.img by nightly developer. you don't need to downgrade twrp. Flash the best build, until the problem solved.

Answer (score -1):

The last update is ok. Now the sysem is updated and everything works.
I think it's magic or someone has made an error